# facebook android sdk sharedialog callback is always success

Tags: java, android, facebook

Using Facebook android sdk version **4.1.1**, I managed to open a shareDialog and share a content using the below code:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Result result) {
                //always gets called

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //do something

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
```

and the callback on ActivityResult code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

the resultCode is always -1 which is **RESULT_OK** regardless whether user pressed **back** or **post** button of the dialog. and the callback's onSuccess function is always called and the postId is always null regardless whether the content is posted or cancelled. Anyone know why is it acting this way?

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: @Razvan check the answer. I already answered my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/890116221030179/) which is a reported bug on facebook developers bug section, this is known and according to the answers given, it seems it's in the design that any form of closing the dialog is considered as success.

Comment: any solution yet, I am waiting for response, is this bugs has been resolved or not

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SDK 7.1.0 and this no longer appears to be an issue. Both the native and web share dialogs are calling the correct callback methods.