# Showing alertbox after posting on Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm using Facebook Android SDK 4.+ to share photo by a button click in my app.

When user click the button, it will open the Facebook share photo page. After posting the photo I want to show alertbox which telling that photo has succesfully posted.

I've been using this

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                    .setHashtag(hastag).build())
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(SellingActivity.this,content);
```

By putting the alertbox after sharedialog.show didn't seem work. It would end up showed after button clicked, then facebook share photo page would show up after that.

Comment: Add callback to `ShareDialog` and show the `AlerrtDialog` on Success . Have alook at [This Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155059/facebook-android-sdk-sharedialog-callback-is-always-success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this method of share `ShareDialog.show(SellingActivity.this,content);` there won't be anycallback. Look at there documention -

```
/**
 * Helper to show the provided {@link com.facebook.share.model.ShareContent} using the provided
 * Fragment. No callback will be invoked.
 *
 * @param fragment android.support.v4.app.Fragment to use to share the provided content
 * @param shareContent Content to share
 */
public static void show(
        final Fragment fragment,
        final ShareContent shareContent) {
    show(new FragmentWrapper(fragment), shareContent);
}
```

If you want callback then we have to use CallbackManager and we need to register for Callback.

In summary below is what you need to do -

1. **Create CallbackManager**

   CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
2. **Create ShareDialog**

   ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity or fragment);
3. **Register for callback**

> ```
> shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onCancel() {
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onError(FacebookException error) {
>
>             }
>         });
> ```

4. **Override onActivityResult**

> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data {
> super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data); callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
> }

---

Comment: I'm using onActivityResult for camera usage...how to differentiate between them so there wont be any conflict?

Comment: requestCode will help you.